# How to automatically create a requirments file with all the installed python packages using pip?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I know that `pip list` will show the lis of installed packages. But I am wondering is there command in `pip` which will help you to copy all the installed packages into a text file `requirements.txt`? Also, is there a way to install all the packages using this `requirement.txt` and not using `pip install` command for each and every package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

to create requirements file. And

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

to auto install packages

[-r flag uses a requirements file to install packages](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files)

Comment: What does `-r` means?

Comment: [Link to some docs about that](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files).

Answer (score 2):

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

to generate a requirements file and

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

to install packages from this file.